# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine, jena

I am playing a little bit around with Jena and I set up a Java Google Web Application project in Eclipse. I downloaded the Jena 2.0 Libraries and added them to the Build path of the project and also to the `/war/WEB-INFO/lib/`folder.

My Simple servlet tries to instantiate a Query using the following line of code

```
...
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
...
```

So there are no compilation errors and as I said the Libarries are both in the Build Path and in the lib folder under WEB-INF (in the war dir.)

When I Run the webapp and execute the servlet I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:78)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:52)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
    at nyx.servlets.PeripheralServlet.extractPlace(PeripheralServlet.java:102)
    at nyx.servlets.PeripheralServlet.doCreate(PeripheralServlet.java:83)
```

The servlet class is PeripheralServlet.java and the line 102 in the method **extractPlace** is the one above where I try to instantiate the Query object.

Could anyone give me a clue on what my problem might be? To me it looks like a missing jar inclusion or something on that line but as I said I included all the jar Jena files to both the Build Path of the project and the lib folder under WEB-INF.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** The weird thing is that the `QueryFactory` it actually gives no error and both `Query` and `QueryFactory` are in the same Jena package right?

**EDIT2:** After repeating the process from scratch and making sure ONLY the needed jars are included once now I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4112)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern$Start.match(Pattern.java:3055)
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1105)
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:535)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalEnvironment.getServerName(LocalEnvironment.java:302)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.getCurrentAppContext(DevAppServerImpl.java:372)
  ...
  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:82)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:704)
  at org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerFactory.getLogger(JCLLoggerFactory.java:64)
  ...
```

If I reload the page after this I get again the original exception. I have been doing some research and I found some related problems dating back to 2009 and so Jena versions 2.6. Assuming we are in 2013 and Jena has evolved to its 2.10 versions I guess they are not so relevant

Comment: Add Apache Jena jar to your eclipse project: https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall06/cps004g/assign/shotgun/addlibrary.html

Comment: I already have all the Jena jars added there. Apart from that this the Google Eclipse Plugin uses Jetty. Does this actually matter?

Comment: You may have a mixture of Jena jars or they may be corrupt - make sure you use only jars from the same version e.g. 2.10.0

Comment: Might the problem be related to a conflict with the Loggers?

Comment: I think this might explain where my problem comes from... but how to solve it? http://articles.qos.ch/classloader.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the following jar to `classpath`

[arq-2.8.1-SHAPSHOT.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/hp/hpl/jena/arq/2.8.1-SHAPSHOT/arq-2.8.1-SHAPSHOT.jar)

Comment: Still getting the same Exception

Comment: @user1450813 Make sure you have added dependencies for this jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with `ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();`
The jars come from the last Jena (2.11.0) and AppEngine 1.8.4 .

`XercesImpl` was having problems, so I removed it from the build path.
But still I found very strange that the error is at runtime and no compilation warning is issued.